# How to submit, a VUE / Cordova Mobile application to Apple Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, vue.js

Under
Apple Store Connect

It states to: 
Submit your builds using Xcode or Application Loader.

But there are no instructions, into how to make the build from VUE/CORDOVA into Xcode

How do you do this?

Have tried opening the project within XCODE, have tried creating a new schema, open the build/www folder from XCODE and still same problem.

done the following

## Deploying

Deploy for android

```
yarn cordova-build-android
```

Deploy for iOS

```
yarn cordova-build-ios
```

Error opening the folder with XCODE

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Answer (score 0):

You open the **XCODE** project actually by opening the `platforms/ios/` or simply the `.codeproj` within the same directory